# Google Cloud Virtual Machine : Unable to resolve external URLs

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

my google cloud VM is not able to resolve external URLs , please see the screenshot.

[image]
any help in addressing this issue , greatly appreciated

As recommended attaching screenshot of resolv.conf
[image]

After restarting systemd-resolved getting below error

```
systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-02-13 10:25:59 UTC; 41s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
 Main PID: 10316 (systemd-resolve)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
           └─10316 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Feb 13 10:26:38 dev.seconize.co systemd-resolved[10316]: Failed to open /etc/hosts: Permission denied
Feb 13 10:26:38 dev.seconize.co systemd-resolved[10316]: Failed to start query: Permission denied
Feb 13 10:26:40 dev.seconize.co systemd-resolved[10316]: Failed to open /etc/hosts: Permission denied
Feb 13 10:26:40 dev.seconize.co systemd-resolved[10316]: Failed to start query: Permission denied
Feb 13 10:26:40 dev.seconize.co systemd-resolved[10316]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with
Feb 13 10:26:40 dev.seconize.co systemd-resolved[10316]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with
Feb 13 10:26:40 dev.seconize.co systemd-resolved[10316]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with
Feb 13 10:26:40 dev.seconize.co systemd-resolved[10316]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with
Feb 13 10:26:40 dev.seconize.co systemd-resolved[10316]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with
Feb 13 10:26:40 dev.seconize.co systemd-resolved[10316]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mit
```

Comment: Looks like your OS thinks that DNS at 127.0.0.1. Did you change DNS servers for your VM? Please run `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and update your question with output.

Comment: By default DNS setting for your VM managed by Google Cloud and no changes needed.

Comment: added the screenshot , yeah we did not touch any of that

Comment: Thanks! Please run `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`, then `sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved` and after that check `cat /etc/resolv.conf` again.  In addition, provide output of `cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf `.

Comment: Do you have admin permissions? Please  provide output of `cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and `cat /etc/hosts`.

Comment: yeah its permissions issue , resolved it now , thanks ! not sure how to close the quesiton

Comment: Please let me know if restart of `systemd-resolved` service with admin privileges helped you to solve this issue.

Comment: /etc/hosts permissions were messed up some how , so had to fix and then restart systemd-resolved to bring it back

Comment: Thanks! Could you post an answer and then accept it? It'll be useful for community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was explained in comments by *@sashank* the cause of this issue was wrong permissions on file `/etc/hosts`. When permissions were fixed restart of `systemd-resolved` service finally solved the issue.